# Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String)" because "this.entityManager" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, entitymanager

I'm trying to use the EntityManager in my Spring Boot application, but I keep getting a NullPointerException when calling methods on it. Specifically, the error message is: "Cannot invoke javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String) because this.entityManager is null."

Here is my repository class

```
package com.cursojava.curso.respositories;

import com.cursojava.curso.models.WebPage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;
@Repository
public class SearchRepositoryImp implements SearchRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<WebPage> search (String textSearch){
        String query = "FROM WebPage WHERE description LIKE :textSearch";
        return entityManager.createQuery(query)
                .setParameter("textSearch",textSearch)
                .getResultList();
    }

}
```

Model class:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Table(name="Webpage")
@ToString @EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter @Setter
public class WebPage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="url")
    private String url;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
}
```

Service class:

```
package com.cursojava.curso.services;

import com.cursojava.curso.models.WebPage;
import com.cursojava.curso.respositories.SearchRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


import java.util.List;

@Service
public class SearchService {
    @Autowired
    private SearchRepository repository;
    public List<WebPage> search(String textSearch) {

        return repository.search(textSearch);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cursojava</groupId>
    <artifactId>curso</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>curso</name>
    <description>clon google</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my aplication properties:

```
# GENERAL
server.port=8080

# DATABASE
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/cursojava?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.dbname=cursojava
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=updatedup
```

I'm trying to get some data from my mySQL database.

Comment: Is nothing getting logged?  How is this *app* getting started?

Comment: nothing is getting logged yet, i only trying to get data from my database using entitymanager, i start the app by clicking in maven spring-boot-run

Comment: Well it looks like you have tomcat running - it has logs

Comment: yeah tomcat run automatically when i run the app

Comment: Hello, I recommend using JPARepository interface instead of entity manager and hard-coded SQL query.

Comment: I would take a wild guess and say that it is likely that you do not have access to your db.  Can you connect using another mysql client?

Comment: Check datasource url. Missing port number?